# Changing dictionary if I send in function

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have one problem with dictionary. Little example:

```
        Dictionary<int, bool> dict = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dict.Add(i, true);
        }
        var dict2 = dict;
        dict2.Clear();
```

after this, I have to clear dictionary. What I need to do, if I need one changing dictionary and one unchanging dictionary?

Comment: `dict2.Clear()` clears also `dict`, i assume this is not desired, is it?

Comment: try this one: var dict2 = dict.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);

Comment: or: var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, bool>(dict);

Answer (score 4):

Create a copy instead of just copying reference:

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, bool>(dict);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is a *class*, so it is a [*reference type*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

When you write

```
var dict2 = dict;
```

You actually assign `dict` and `dict2` to the same references. That's why when you want to use [`Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5txwy7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, **it effects both of them**. You should copy them instead of copying their references. Like;

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, bool>(dict);
```

From *[C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx)*;

> Variables of value types directly contain their data whereas variables
>   of reference types store references to their data, the latter being
>   known as objects. With reference types, it is possible for two
>   variables to reference the same object and thus possible for
>   operations on one variable to affect the object referenced by the
>   other variable. With value types, the variables each have their own
>   copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one to
>   affect the other.